# Data Analysis with Pandas throws nothing

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Write a function called proportion_of_education which returns the proportion of children in the dataset who had a mother with the education levels equal to less than high school (<12), high school (12), more than high school but not a college graduate (>12) and college degree.

This function should return a dictionary in the form of (use the correct numbers, do not round numbers):

```
{"less than high school":0.2,
"high school":0.4,
"more than high school but not college":0.2,
"college":0.2}
```

The code I copied and tried to use is as following

```
def proportion_of_education():
    # your code goes here
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    # raise NotImplementedError()
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    df = pd.read_csv("assests/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)
    EDUS=df['EDUC1']
    edus=np.sort(EDUS.values)
    poe={"less than high school":0,
        "high school":0,
        "more than high school but not college":0,
        "college":0}
    n=len(edus)
    poe["less than high school"]=np.sum(edus==1)/n
    poe["high school"]=np.sum(edus==2)/n
    poe["more than high school but not college"]=np.sum(edus==3)/n
    poe["college"]=np.sum(edus==4)/n
    return poe
```

```
assert type(proportion_of_education())==type({}), "You must return a dictionary."
assert len(proportion_of_education()) == 4, "You have not returned a dictionary with four items in it."
assert "less than high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "more than high school but not college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
```

It's supposed to print out

```
{"less than high school":0.2,
    "high school":0.4,
    "more than high school but not college":0.2,
    "college":0.2}
```

However, Notebook throws nothing. Not an error, prints out absolutely nothing despite me running this multiple times, using different paths. What could be the problem.

Comment: You could do a better job of creating the dictionary. Perhaps something like `poe = df['EDU'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict(); return poe;`

Comment: Also it looks like there are only asserts here, but no "print" statement (something you'll need to have if you want to "print" something).

Comment: in normal script/program you has to use `print()` to display anything - `print(proportion_of_education())` or in two steps `results = proportion_of_education()` `print(results)`. In Notebookyou can also use `print(...)` or at least you have to execute function without any other elements - `proportion_of_education()` - and Notebook should automatically display result from last function in cell. But you use `proportion_of_education()` inside `assert` which gets results from function so Notebook has nothing to display.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `len(edus==1)` instead of `np.sum` and similarly with the others

Answer (score 0):

`df = pd.read_csv("assests/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)` you have to replace this line with the line below because you write the wrong spelling of assets.

`df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)`

Answer (score 0):

The right code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def proportion_of_education():
    
    df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col = 0)
    
    EDUS = df['EDUC1']
    edus = np.sort(EDUS.values)
    
    poe = {"less than high school": 0,
        "high school": 0,
        "more than high school but not college": 0,
        "college": 0}
    n = len(edus)
    
    poe["less than high school"] = np.sum(edus == 1)/n
    poe["high school"] = np.sum(edus == 2)/n
    poe["more than high school but not college"] = np.sum(edus == 3)/n
    poe["college"] = np.sum(edus == 4)/n
    
    return poe
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def proportion_of_education():

```
# your code goes here
# YOUR CODE HERE

df = pd.read_csv(r'assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
EDUC1 = df['EDUC1']
educ1 = np.sort(EDUC1.values)
poe = {"less than high school": 0,
    "high school": 0,
    "more than high school but not college": 0,
    "college": 0}
total = len(educ1)
poe['less than high school'] = len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 1])/total
poe['high school'] = len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 2])/total
poe['more than high school but not college'] = len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 3])/total
poe['college'] = len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 4])/total
return poe
raise NotImplementedError()
```

proportion_of_education()

Answer (score 0):

Type this in the first cell below the question to read the data

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
df
```

In next cell

```
def proportion_of_education():
    # your code goes here
    cat=pd.value_counts(df['EDUC1'])
    total=sum(cat)
    a_dict=dict(cat)
    s=pd.Series(a_dict)
    f=lambda x: x/total
    s=s.apply(f)
    s_dict=dict(s)
    s_dict['less than high school'] = s_dict.pop(1)
    s_dict['high school'] = s_dict.pop(2)
    s_dict['more than high school but not college'] = s_dict.pop(3)
    s_dict['college'] = s_dict.pop(4)
    return s_dict

    raise NotImplementedError()
```

To check, type this in next cell

```
proportion_of_education()
```

The final cell of this question is below here

```
assert type(proportion_of_education())==type({}), "You must return a dictionary."
assert len(proportion_of_education()) == 4, "You have not returned a dictionary with four items in it."
assert "less than high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "high school" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "more than high school but not college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
assert "college" in proportion_of_education().keys(), "You have not returned a dictionary with the correct keys."
```

In 'EDUC1' column, there would be 1 2 3 4

=> 1 - less than high school

=> 2 - high school

=> 3 - more than high school but not college

=> 4 - college

lambda function is used to calculate proportion for all categories

.pop() method is used to rename **1** as **less than high school** and similarly for other categories

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    def proportion_of_education():
    # your code goes here
    # YOUR CODE HERE
        df=pd.read_csv('assets/NISPUF17.csv',index_col=0)
        poe = {"less than high school": len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 1])/len(df),
"high school": len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 2])/len(df),
"more than high school but not college": len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 3])/len(df),
"college": len(df[df['EDUC1'] == 4])/len(df)}
      return poe


    proportion_of_education()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your contribution, but while this code may answer the question, it would be much more helpful to include an explanation. Also, you have some indentation errors so the code probably won't work exactly as posted.

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE SOLUTION

```
def proportion_of_education():
    import pandas as pd


    df = pd.read_csv("NISPUF17.csv")

    df = df["EDUC1"]
    lessThanHighSchool = (df[df == 1].count()) / df.count()
    highScool = (df[df == 2].count()) / df.count()
    moreThanHighSchoolNotCollage = (df[df == 3].count()) / df.count()
    collage = (df[df == 4].count()) / df.count()

    dictionary = {"less than high school ":lessThanHighSchool ,
        "high school":highScool,
        "more than high school but not college":moreThanHighSchoolNotCollage,
        "college":collage
        }

    return dictionary
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the easy solution is:

df=pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col=0)

```
df['EDUC1 Label'] =df["EDUC1"].map({
    1:"less than high school",
    2:"high school",
    3:"more than high school but not college",
    4:"college"})
total=df["EDUC1 Label"].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()
return total
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def proportion_of_education():
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_csv("assets/NISPUF17.csv", index_col= 0)
  EDUC1 = df['EDUC1']
  less = len(df[df['EDUC1']== 1]['EDUC1'])/len(EDUC1)
  high = len(df[df['EDUC1']== 2]['EDUC1'])/len(EDUC1)
  more = len(df[df['EDUC1']== 3]['EDUC1'])/len(EDUC1)
  college = len(df[df['EDUC1']== 4]['EDUC1'])/len(EDUC1)
  poe = {"less than high school":less,
  "high school":high,
  "more than high school but not college":more,
  "college":college}
  return poe
  raise NotImplementedError()
proportion_of_education()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).